# Android NFC Battery Off mode

Tags: android, nfc

I'm currently investigating how NFC works, doing some tutorials, making some small apps to read/write/do_things when detect RFID tags...

But i'm currently wondering, how does the card emulation works ? I mean i know the phone support this mode. (cf : 
http://www.nearfieldcommunicationsworld.com/2011/02/13/35913/uncovered-the-hidden-nfc-potential-of-the-google-nexus-s-and-the-nokia-c7/ )

But what if the phone is off ? It seems the component used in the Nexus S for example supports "Battery low / Battery off" mode. But how does it work ? (http://www.nxp.com/documents/leaflet/75016890.pdf).

Thanks.

Clement.M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might be guessing here but normally the key to NFC (at least with rfid cards) is that the base station provides the device with the power needed to transmit the data....so maybe once the data is set there is no need for mobile battery...

Edit: just saw it in the datasheet. The Chip supports "Power by field mode" so like a RFID card your device is powered by the electromagnetic field the base station emits. Probably there is a non-volatile memory inside the chip which does not need any constant power and can then be used as memory of the field powered device.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Well i was guessing that the chip could work using the "power by field mode" :). But i'm wondering how it will work when the user will use his phone as a credit card or a bus ticket. I mean for example, when we buy a ticket online with the phone, maybe it register the SIM code of the user and then, because the SIM card is linked to the chip, it double check this ID ?

Comment: Sorry, I thought maybe you were missing the electronic background behind this :) Well if you ask me there is no fixed way to realise the way it's used as a CC, for example if MasterCard starts NFC payment, they'll think about what data the cross reference (will the use a user/key pair or a SIM-ID/Password pair or some other type of unique key, maybe even the IMEI and a stored password. Point is they transfer it to the chips EEPROM where it is stored for power-by-field operation, then it's transferred....as I said AFAIK there is no standard way yet, payment services will come up with one :)